# Flutter MobX Observer does not fire upon @action

Tags: flutter, mobx

I'm using a MultiProvider which wraps my whole app. I'm already using another Store/Observer for authentication/login and that part works as it should.
I just added another store which reflects the photos a user has taken and which then get displayed at two different places before uploading.

The "taking the photo" and "insert them into the store" works fine. The part which is then supposed to reactively display the photos... not so much.

Relevant code:

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:mobx/mobx.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

part 'photoview_store.g.dart';

class PhotoviewStore = _PhotoviewStore with _$PhotoviewStore;

abstract class _PhotoviewStore with Store {
  @observable
  List<File> images = [];

  @computed
  int get length => images.length;

  @action
  Future getImage({bool fromGallery: true}) async {
    ImageSource source = fromGallery ? ImageSource.gallery : ImageSource.camera;
    File _image;
    try {
      _image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: source);
      if(images.length >= 3) images.removeLast();
      images.insert(0, _image);
      print('New length: ${images.length}');
    } catch(_) {
      print('Error getting image');
    }
  }

  @action
  void removePicture(int index) {
    images.removeAt(index);
  }
}
```

The `@computed` I added because I thought it might be problematic to access `images.length` in the Observer. Doesn't do anything, though.

```
class NeuesAnliegen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NeuesAnliegenState createState() => _NeuesAnliegenState();
}

class _NeuesAnliegenState extends State<NeuesAnliegen> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin{
[...]
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final photoStore = Provider.of<PhotoviewStore>(context);
    super.build(context);
    [...]
       Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: Observer(builder: (_) {
                      print(photoStore.length);
                      if(photoStore.length < 1) return Container();
                      return GestureDetector(
                        child: Image.file(photoStore.images[0], height: 100),
                        onTap: () { },
                      );
                    },)
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: Observer(builder: (_) {
                      if(photoStore.length < 2) return Container();
                      return GestureDetector(
                        child: Image.file(photoStore.images[1], height: 100),
                        onTap: () { },
                      );
                    },)
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: Observer(builder: (_) {
                      if(photoStore.length < 3) return Container();
                      return GestureDetector(
                        child: Image.file(photoStore.images[2], height: 100),
                        onTap: () { },
                      );
                    },)                  )
                ],
              ),
    [...]
                  Expanded(
                      child: RaisedButton.icon(
                        onPressed: () => photoStore.getImage(fromGallery: false,),
                        icon: Icon(Icons.camera),
                        label: Text('Foto aufnehmen')
                      ),
                    ),
```

So, I can take a photo just fine and it does get added to the `images` list but the `Observable` never fires.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, seems that this part

```
@observable
List<File> images = [];
```

does not work (currently?)

Replacing it with

```
final images = ObservableList<File>.of([]);
```

will yield the wanted results

Comment: Indeed, it's not a bug. The observables are trigger when the **instance** is changing, when it's the list, this is the same instance so it doesn't rebuild.

Comment: You can create an `ObservableList` (which is the cleaner way on my point of view) or you can recreate a new instance : `images = [file_1, file_2, ];`

Answer (score 0):

```
@observable
List<File> images = new List<File>().asObservable();
```

Worked to me.